# creating async AJAX while alert() is opened

Tags: javascript, ajax, alert

My browser sends keep-alive async calls to the server every 20 seconds using `window.setTimeout()`. The problem: when `alert()` pops out, the AJAX calls are suspended. If the user waits a while before dismissing the popup - the server will (wrongly) close the login session.

We use `alert()` to popup error messages, and I can't use other methods since this is the product definition.

Any way to workaround this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`alert()` as well as `prompt()` all block the UI thread which means all other operations get suspended.

I suggest you use modal windows instead, like [the ones in jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal).

Answer (score 3):

As @JosephtheDreamer mentioned in his answer, `alert`, `prompt` and `confirm` will all block the UI.

If you really want to use an `alert`, then you could use WebWorkers. They run in a separate thread and as such are not subject to UI blocking.  They have [decent support](http://caniuse.com/#search=webworkers), but as usual will not work in IE < 10.

This is actually quite complicated to do, so I would recommend following @JosephtheDreamer's advice and going with modal windows. They're not hard to do and will solve the problem more simply.

For more information about WebWorkers, see [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers).

Comment: Ahh, I knew I left something out. It was the `confirm()`. Haven't used those for a very long time.

Comment: I just used it today =) In my case, blocking the UI was intentional. There was a button to delete everything in the database, so I wanted to make sure the user got the message.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, why can't you use something other than alert? Alerts are not very attractive or user-friendly. A simple modal window (like the [jQuery UI one](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) for example) is far better...

Answer (score 0):

try to replace default alert behaviour

```
window.alert = function(message) {
// put your dialog box launching code here.
```

}

or this

```
alert = function(foo) {
// some functionality
```

};